# -finstrument-functions doesn't work with dynamically loaded g++ shared objects (.so)

Tags: c++, linux, g++, profiling, shared-libraries

I am testing -finstrument-functions with g++ shared object (.so) files on Ubuntu these days. I found a strange behavior that -finstrument-functions seems to work only if the library is statically linked. If I link to the library with dlopen/dlsym etc., the functionality of the code still works, but it won't call the __cyg_profile* functions.

Here are some codes to quickly reproduce the problem:

MyLib.h

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_H__
#define __MYLIB_H__
class MyLib
{
public:
    void sayHello();
};
#endif
```

MyLib.cpp

```
#include "MyLib.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void MyLib::sayHello()
{
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
}
```

MyLibStub.cpp (C interface to the .so)

```
#include "MyLib.h"

extern "C" void LoadMyLib ()
{
    MyLib().sayHello();
}
```

Trace.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
    void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void *this_fn, void *call_site)
        __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
    void __cyg_profile_func_exit(void *this_fn, void *call_site)
        __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
}
#endif

void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void* this_fn, void* call_site)
{
    printf("entering %p\n", (int*)this_fn);
}

void __cyg_profile_func_exit(void* this_fn, void* call_site)
{
    printf("exiting %p\n", (int*)this_fn);
}
```

MainStatic.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" void LoadMyLib ();

int main()
{
    LoadMyLib();
    return 0;
}
```

MainDynamic.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

const char* pszLibName  = "libMyLib.so.0.0";
const char* pszFuncName  = "LoadMyLib";

int main()
{
    void* pLibHandle = dlopen(pszLibName, RTLD_NOW);
    if(!pLibHandle) {
        return 1;
    }
    void (*pFuncLoad)() = 0;
    //Resolve the function in MyLibStub.cpp
    pFuncLoad = (void (*)())dlsym(pLibHandle, pszFuncName);
    if(!pFuncLoad) {
        return 1;
    }
    pFuncLoad();
    dlclose(pLibHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

and compile with the following commands (under Ubuntu 11.10):

> ```
> g++ -g -finstrument-functions -Wall -Wl,-soname,libMyLib.so.0 -shared -fPIC -rdynamic MyLib.cpp MyLibStub.cpp Trace.cpp -o libMyLib.so.0.0  
> ln -s libMyLib.so.0.0 libMyLib.so.0  
> ln -s libMyLib.so.0.0 libMyLib.so  
> g++ MainStatic.cpp -g -Wall -lMyLib -L./ -o MainStatic   
> g++ MainDynamic.cpp -g -Wall -ldl -o MainDynamic
> ```

when called with `./MainStatic`

it gives something like:

> ```
> entering 0xb777693f
> entering 0xb777689b
> exiting 0xb777689b
> exiting 0xb777693f
> entering 0xb7776998
> entering 0xb777680c
> Hello
> exiting 0xb777680c
> exiting 0xb7776998
> ```

however, when called with `./MainDynamic`

it only gives a "Hello".

> ```
> Hello
> ```

Does anybody here know why there is such difference between statically and dynamically linked libraries? Is there any solution to make it work even when dynamically loaded? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any suggestion for this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910918/how-to-compile-a-cpp-and-then-link-it-to-a-shared-library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is expected.

In order to understand it, you first need to know that the dynamic loader searches for symbols using a linked list, in the order that different `ELF` images were loaded. At the head of that list is the main executable itself, followed by all libraries directly linked to it. When you `dlopen()` some library, it gets appended to the *tail* of the list.

So when the code in the library you just loaded calls `__cyg_profile_func_enter`, the loader searches the list for the first definition of that function. That first definition happens to be the default one, provided by libc.so.6, which is near the end of the list, but is *before* your `dlopen()`ed library.

You can observe all of this by running:

```
LD_DEBUG=symbols,bindings ./MainDynamic
```

and looking for `__cyg_profile_func_enter` in the output.

So, what do you have to do in order to see your instrumentation? You *have* to get your own `__cyg_profile_func_enter` somewhere *before* the one from `libc.so.6`. One way to do that is to link it into your main executable. Or link it into a shared library that is *directly* linked to your executable (i.e. *not* `dlopen()`d one).

Once you do that, your implementation will be the first one on the list, and it will win over the one in `libc.so.6`, and you will see the output it generates.

Comment: any solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910918/how-to-compile-a-cpp-and-then-link-it-to-a-shared-library and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896140/chronological-trace-of-function-calls-in-c-using-etrace

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
dlopen(pszLibName, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
```

Then symbols defined in a library will be preferred to global symbols