# How to use etrace with a dynamic library for chronological traceing of function calls in C++?

Tags: c++, c, perl, macros, profiling

**Background:**

I have one big simulation tool, and I need to understand its logical behavior. In order to do that, the most of help I would get if I have the chronological order of function calls, for a minimal working example.

I found many tools online, like [CygProfiler](http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/CygProfiler/) and [etrace](https://github.com/elcritch/etrace). I became so miserable on finding a solution that I started to follow the craziest solution of using "step into" with the debugger. Which is a good option if you have a small program but not a complete simulation tool.

---

**Problem:**

One of the problems I face is that the above-mentioned solutions are originally meant for `C` and they generate a static file (`*.o`) when compiled. On the other hand the simulation tool generates a shared library (`.so`). I don't have much knowledge on lower level stuff so I seem to fail when I try linking them.

I looked specifically at the `etrace` [documentation](https://github.com/elcritch/etrace/blob/master/README), and it says:

> To see how to modify ptrace.c to work with a dynamic library, look at
>   the example2 directory. The sources there also create a stand-alone
>   executable, but the PTRACE_REFERENCE_FUNCTION macro is defined just as
>   it would be for a dynamic library.

If you look at the repo there is no difference between the files in `example` and `example2` folders. Only there is an extra `.h` file in `example2`.

On the other hand, if you look at `src/ptrace.c` there it says:

> When using ptrace on a dynamic library, you must set the
>     PTRACE_REFERENCE_FUNCTION macro to be the name of a function in the
>     library. The address of this function when loaded will be the first
>     line output to the trace file and will permit the translation of the
>     other entry and exit pointers to their symbolic names. You may set
>     the macro PTRACE_INCLUDE with any #include directives needed for
>     that function to be accesible to this source file.

a little below there is the commented code:

```
/* When using ptrace on a dynamic library, the following must be defined:
#include "any files needed for PTRACE_REFERENCE_FUNCTION"
#define PTRACE_REFERENCE_FUNCTION functionName
`*/
```

---

**Question:**

In essence the question is the following: How to use `etrace` with a dynamic library?

Do I need to #include any files?

> To trace a stand-alone program, there is no need to #include any
>   additional file. Just link your code against ptrace.c and use the
>   -finstrument-functions option as a compile option for gcc. This should do it.

How do I link a C++ code which is built via makefiles against `ptrace.c`

**Final Note:** I would appreciate if someone bears with my ignorance and provides a step-by-step solution to my question.

---

**Update 1:**

I managed to add the libraries related to etrace to the simulation tool, and it executes fine.

However, (probably because the scripts are too old, or are not meant for use with C++) I get the following error when using the [perl script](https://github.com/elcritch/etrace/blob/master/src/etrace.pl) provided by default by `etrace`

> ```
> Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable"
> ```

Probably this changes a bit the nature of this question, turning it more to a perl related issue at this point.

If this problem is solved, I hope `etrace` will work with a complicated project and I will provide the details

---

**Update 2:**

I took the suggestions from @Harry, and I believe that would work in most projects. However in my case I get the following from the perl script:

```
Use of uninitialized value within %SYMBOLTABLE in list assignment at etrace2.pl line 99, <CALL_DATA> line 1.

\-- ???
|   \-- ???
\-- ???
|   \-- ???
|   |   \-- ???
\-- ???
|   \-- ???
\-- ???
|   \-- ???
\-- ???
|   \-- ???
\-- ???
|   \-- ???
\-- ???
|   \-- ???
```

Due to autegenerated makefiles I used the [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36959597/4317408) to load the shared library for etrace.so which I got as follows:

```
gcc -g -finstrument-functions -shared -fPIC ptrace.c -o etrace.so -I <path-to-etrace>
```

I created the dummy etrace.h inside the tool:

```
#ifndef __ETRACE_H_
#define __ETRACE_H_

#include <stdio.h>

void Crumble_buy(char * what, int quantity, char * unit);


void Crumble_buy(char * what, int quantity, char * unit)
{
    printf("buy %d %s of %s\n", quantity, unit, what);
}

#endif
```

and used `Crumble_buy` for the `#define` and the `etrace.h` for the `#include`.

Comment: Sympathies. Even if you find what you want, unless the program is really simple, you will get probably get a file of many Mb, mostly containing low-level stuff that doesn't tell you much. When I want to know how something works I use two methods. 1) Step Into/Over, which you looked down on, but don't. 2) Let it rip, and then hit "pause" or Ctrl-C to [*stop it at random*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771). Do it a few times, each time looking at who is calling whom and why. This quickly gets you an understanding of how it spends the bulk of its time.

Comment: iron mike, you're probably right. The amount of time I spent figuring out how this could work, I could have stepped into millions of functions :/... one option would be to compile with `-finstruction-functions` flag only the files which I want to see. that would ignore the lower level stuff...

Comment: I'm flattered, I guess :) But really, try it. Don't expect instant results. What you want to know will gradually dawn on you. I've done it several times. If there were a better way, I and others would have found it.

Comment: I use Boost Log and created a wrapper for it:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html. I created "TraceIn" (for function entry), "TraceOut" (for function exit), and other Severity Levels like "Verbose", "Info", "Warning", and "Error".  For each log entry, there are timestamp, thread ID, level, and function name added.

Comment: @gxy can you submit an answer with your solution?

Comment: @cross Can you be more specific with your question. The etrace utility as is works for me. The simulator you want to trace, are you compiling it because for this to work you need to be and if you're compiling it whats stoping you adding this?

Comment: @Harry wrote an update...

Comment: Can you provide a sample C++ source file with a relevant Makefile that would produce minimal example of the binary that `etrace.pl` has trouble analyzing?

Comment: I would, but that is unfeasible as it is a complete simulation framework. But you can find all you asked here: https://github.com/sommer/veins

Comment: @Cross, do you want this to work on Mac or Linux.

Comment: @Harry linux would suffice atm

Comment: Then I think you're all set with the Perl changes I gave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fixing the Perl Script

> Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable"

This is a warning from `hex` because it's detecting a possibly non-portable value (something > 32bits).

At the very top of the script, add this:

```
use bigint qw/hex oct/;
```

When this tool was written, I suspect the people were on 32-bit machines. You can compile the program using 32-bit with the flag `-m32`, but if you change the perl script as mentioned above you won't need to.

Note, if you're on a Mac, you can't use `mknod` the way it's used in the script to create a pipe; you need to use `mkfifo` with no arguments instead.

On Linux, adding the `bigint` fix above works. You then need to run both commands from the same directory, I did this using `example2`:

```
../src/etrace.pl crumble
# Switch to a different terminal
./crumble
```

and I get this on the Mac and Linux

```
\-- main
|   \-- Crumble_make_apple_crumble
|   |   \-- Crumble_buy_stuff
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_buy
|   |   \-- Crumble_prepare_apples
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_skin_and_dice
|   |   \-- Crumble_mix
|   |   \-- Crumble_finalize
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   \-- Crumble_cook
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_put
|   |   |   \-- Crumble_bake
```

### About the Dynamic Library...

When you load a dynamic library, the address in the object file is not the address that will be used when running. What etrace does is take a function name from a header you specify. For example, in the case of `example2`, this would be the following:

```
#include "crumble.h"
#define PTRACE_REFERENCE_FUNCTION Crumble_buy
```

You would then edit the makefile to make sure that the header file can be found:

```
CFLAGS = -g -finstrument-functions -I.
```

Note the addition of the include `-I.`. The address of the symbol from the header (in our case, `Crumble_buy`) is used to calculate the offset between the object file and the actual address; this allows the program to calculate the correct address to find the symbol.

If you look at the output of `nm`, you get something like the following:

```
0000000100000960 T _Crumble_bake
00000001000005b0 T _Crumble_buy
0000000100000640 T _Crumble_buy_stuff
00000001000009f0 T _Crumble_cook
```

The addresses on the left are relative, that is, at runtime, these addresses actually change. The etrace.pl program is storing these in a hash like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4294969696' => '_Crumble_bake',
          '4294969424' => '_Crumble_put',
          '4294970096' => '_main',
          '4294969264' => '_Crumble_mix',
          '4294970704' => '_gnu_ptrace_close',
          '4294967296' => '__mh_execute_header',
          '4294968752' => '_Crumble_buy',
          '4294968896' => '_Crumble_buy_stuff',
          '4294969952' => '_Crumble_make_apple_crumble',
          '4294969184' => '_Crumble_prepare_apples',
          '4294971512' => '___GNU_PTRACE_FILE__',
          '4294971504' => '_gnu_ptrace.first',
          '4294970208' => '_gnu_ptrace',
          '4294970656' => '___cyg_profile_func_exit',
          '4294970608' => '___cyg_profile_func_enter',
          '4294969552' => '_Crumble_finalize',
          '4294971508' => '_gnu_ptrace.active',
          '4294969840' => '_Crumble_cook',
          '4294969088' => '_Crumble_skin_and_dice',
          '4294970352' => '_gnu_ptrace_init'
        };
```

Note the leading underscore because this is on a Mac using clang. At runtime, these addresses are not correct, but their relative offsets are. If you can work out what the offset is, you can adjust the addresses you get at runtime to find the actual symbol. The code that does this follows:

```
 if ($offsetLine =~ m/^$REFERENCE_OFFSET\s+($SYMBOL_NAME)\s+($HEX_NUMBER)$/) {
    # This is a dynamic library; need to calculate the load offset
    my $offsetSymbol  = "_$1";
    my $offsetAddress = hex $2; 

    my %offsetTable = reverse %SYMBOLTABLE;

    print Dumper(\%offsetTable);
    $baseAddress = $offsetTable{$offsetSymbol} - $offsetAddress;
    #print("offsetSymbol == $offsetSymbol\n");
    #print("offsetAddress == $offsetAddress\n");
    #print("baseoffsetAddress == $offsetAddress\n");
    $offsetLine = <CALL_DATA>;
  } else {
    # This is static
    $baseAddress = 0;
  }
```

This is what the line `#define PTRACE_REFERENCE_FUNCTION Crumble_buy` is for. The `C` code in ptrace is using that MACRO, and if defined, outputting the address of that function as the first thing. It then calculates the offset, and for all subsequent addresses, adjusts them by this amount, looking up the correct symbol in the hash.

Comment: your solution sounds reasonable, and I am certain it would work in most cases... but in the case of this big project I get questions marks from the perl script. See the update.

Comment: It's using dynamic libraries and is unable to resolve the symbols or the address offsets are wrong. You keep changing the question ie it's a moving target, if I answer your next question there'll be another question and another for the next several days. You need to understand how etrace works and get it working using both the static and dynamic methods using the crumble program. At the moment it sounds like you're trying to add something you don't understand to a program you don't understand in order to understand it.

Comment: I agree completely with what you say... `note to self and others:` probably spending couple of hours understanding how the tool works saves much more time on trying to patch things here and there... but since the questions has got some attention it would be helpful to bring it to some conclusion

Comment: I accepted your answer for your efforts to solve the question. However (if you find fit) you might want to extend it to provide a definite solution.

Comment: My solution worked on Linux and I also had it working on the Mac with some tweaking for underscores etc. I'm not sure what else I could do.